# Performance counters indexes windows pdh c

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I'm writing an utility, which should get current CPU load. At the moment It's working and using `\Processor(_Total)\% process time` in my localization. For multi-lingual support I'm getting counter name from registry by `PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex`.

Now code looks like

```
PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex(NULL, 6, processorTime, &cbPathSize);
PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex(NULL, 238, processor, &cbPathSize);
PDH_COUNTER_PATH_ELEMENTS elements = {NULL, processor, "_Total", NULL, NULL, processorTime};
PdhMakeCounterPath(&elements, fullPath, &cbPathSize, 0);
```

and I wanna remove hard-coded constants 6 and 238.

Are there some constants which means index for `Processor` and `% process time`?

Answer (score 2):

The indexes differ between systems, you have to determine them dynamically. The procedure is hinted at in the [MSDN documentation of PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

1. Retrieve the REG_MULTI_SZ data of the the registry value `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Perflib\009\Counter`

Note: "009" stands for English. That key always exists, even on machines with different language versions of Windows.

2. Look for your (English) counter/object name in the returned data. Format: index followed by English counter/object name, e.g.:

   6
   % Processor Time

There is your index. Just convert from string to DWORD and use it with PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex.